# Javascript: Creating a graph from scratch?

Tags: javascript

So i need to create a basic bar graph from scratch using javascript, i tried setting some things such as, I attempted to start trying to define some values but it all went wrong.

The task is to create a program that will accept some of this data, input by the user, and to produce a graph that is suitably formatted.
The output could be made to look like this:

[image: I]

Here is the data that is provided

[image]

How would I simply even attempt this from scratch?

Comment: "From scratch" means without using any graphing library?

Comment: I'm 99% sure you're not provided with a .jpg data image

Comment: copying and pasting the values into the question made it unreadable so i took a gyazo instead

Comment: @JohnSmith well, you can always explain the *type of data* you're provided with. How can we possibly know from an image? What have you tried? What are your concerns? What about the Y axis values? What is your research and code you already have that you attempted on your own on that matter? Have any?

Comment: @JohnSmith please [edit] your question and add more info and code. (Not *all* the code, but the minimum needed to get a *better picture*)

Comment: @JohnSmith also take a look at this page: http://www.chartjs.org/

Comment: http://d3js.org/ is a fantastic library for creating a range of graphs and other graphical data presentation. It might be a bit of overkill for such a simple graph but it would be no harm in learning it.

Comment: that's the problem i cant use scripts like that or anything, this is all im provided http://gyazo.com/8278a8f487bbd140502271220a8dd65a , http://gyazo.com/46d90e964623dbcb39e23141d94c4f4d

Answer (score 3):

Given all the complexities of charting, I think most people just use one of the many open source charting libraries.  [SparkLines](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about) is just one example.

Yet, sometimes you just want a simple chart without adding a library. And a bar chart is one of the easiest to build.  The code snippet below is *very* basic, but it is enough to get OP started with the homework assignment.

Run code snippet to view:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <style type="text/css">
        #chart {background-color: lightyellow; position: relative; height:200px; width: 200px; border: 1px black solid; display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom; font-size: 10px; }
        .bar {position: absolute; bottom: 0; display:inline-block; width: 10px; margin: 2px; background-color: lightpink;}
    </style>
    
    <div id="chart"></div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      
      
      var i, max, min, h, html='', data = [34.7,68.9,65.1,130.2,208.6,172.8,155.0,168.6,134.4,52.7,94.5,41.5];
      
      max = min = data[0];

      for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        if (max < data[i]) max = data[i];
        if (min > data[i]) min = data[i];
      }

      
      for(i=0; i< data.length; i++) {
        h = Math.round( 100 * ((data[i] - min) / max));
        html += '<div class="bar" style="height:' + h + '%; left:' + (12 * i) + 'px">' + data[i] + '</div>';
      }
      
      document.getElementById('chart').innerHTML = html;
      
     </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Group the values on the X axis so theres the number of groups left that you want on the X axis
2. Calculate the average of Y for each group
3. Get the maximum value of all your groups; say it's 320
4. Take a height in pixels that you want your graph to have; say 200
5. Calculate the height in pixels that each group has with the rule of three:

   ```
   320       =  200
   pixel-y   =  group-y
   ```
6. Paint the respective group on your graph

For example, if a group has a Y value of 120:

```
320       =  200
pixel-y   =  120

pixel-y = (320 * 120) / 200
pixel-y = 192
```